# How to change color of tabs in ionic app?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I wish to change the active color of my tabs to a custom one.
I would also like to change the colour of the icons if possible.

Currently the tab I am on is the color positive and the rest of the tabs are grey.

For those of you who are not familar with ionic but are css geniuses, 
ionic has a number of default set colours, example: positive=blue, assertive=red.

Here is what I have so far:

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">    

 <!-- Home Tab -->    

 <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-android-home" href="#/app/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="app-home"></ion-nav-view> 
  </ion-tab>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs-color-active-positive, .tabs {
color: #c49137 !important;

}
```

I have messed around with the css code and declartions but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache ? And re-built ? Chrome development tools are indispensable : (f12 // Rightclick inspect element) to see where the CSS is being called.

Comment: I got it sorted now. Thanks for replying Pogrindis. Normally this would be the first thing to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `.tabs` isn't pointing to anything. So it needs to be corrected or removed from the CSS selector. If you want to target the other 2 elements, you need to add classes to them.

Typically, icons will change color if they have a transparent background & are created as .PNGs. Try changing the color of these Font Awesome icons to see how they can change from black to blue: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Now to fix the code:

I assume that there is a `</ion-tabs>` tag, which is missing from the example above. So I've added it here, alone with additional classes for `<ion-tab>` & `<ion-nav-view>`. The `.tab` class allows you to group multiple tabs together when targeting them using jQuery or via CSS.

HTML:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">      
    <ion-tab class="tab tab-home" title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-android-home" href="#/app/home">
        <ion-nav-view class="nav-view-home" name="app-home"></ion-nav-view> 
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The `.tabs-icon-top` class name is a root class name. It's optional. It's recommended to use that, so that your CSS code/color won't spill out onto anywhere else on the page which has a `.tab` or a `.tab-home` class name applied to it. You may use any one of these CSS selectors & you don't need this entire stack. They simply become more specific as they progress to the right. (Feel free to delete lines 1, 2 or 3 & the comma, as needed.)

CSS:

```
.tabs-icon-top,
.tabs-icon-top .tab,
.tabs-icon-top .tab .nav-view-home {
    color: #c49137;
}
```

You can also use this to select all of the tabs, which are namespaced:

```
.tabs-icon-top .tab {
    color: #c49137;
}
```

Or this to select an individual tab:

```
.tabs-icon-top .nav-view-home {
    color: #c49137;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clomp. I got the tabs changed to a custom colour, following your answer. Really appreciate this, a prime example of a great answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that I could help you out. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sass, you can just put the following in your CSS file:

```
ion-tabs {
  @include tabs-standard-color('tabs-color-active-[custom name here]', 
   [main color], [color if not selected]);
}
```

This way you can also avoid overriding the existing styles and just create a custom class. You could also choice to override the `$positive` to change every element that uses that color.

---

From the Sass I was able to get the CSS, it doesn't look pretty, but it should do the trick:

```
ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-custom .tab-item {
  color: [inactive color]; 
}

ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-custom .tab-item.tab-item-active, ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-custom .tab-item.active, ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-custom .tab-item.activated {
    color: [active color]; 
}
```

Comment: This would work if I was using SASS, but I am not. Thanks Dexter for replying, hopefully this will help someone else who uses scss.

Comment: I have added a CSS version of the same solution, perhaps you could give that a shot?

Comment: Sorry Dexter, it did not work, it resulted in the tabs crushing together and no color. I have selected the above as the answer that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs-md .tabbar {
    background: #00c6ff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```